# How to split by "/" and store as hierarchical like tree in java?

Tags: java, tree

I am trying to store Instance objects hierarchical like tree data structure.
In my case, i will get list of Strings like:

"A/B/C",
"A/B/D",
"A/T/P",
"Q/W/E"  etc.

"/" represents their hierarchy. For example A parent of B, B parent of C and D.

Each of these letter represent a Instance object so after split these according to "/" how can i do store these letter as a Instances objects in a list by hierarchical in java?. Can i also need to add parent or child or both fields in Instance object.

Instace object:

```
public class Instance { 

  private String name;

  private String description;

  private int type;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to revisit your data structure, `Instance` class. From the example that you provided, it seems you are trying to create a Tree data structure, where a node can have multiple children. You need to design your `Instance` class that can handle multiple children in a node. 
Try using List of Instances for handling children.

Your class would look like-

```
class Instance {
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private int type;
  List<Instance> children;
}
```

Try splitting your input string and iterate through each substring, check if you already have `Instance` object with the name. If not you will create a new `Instance` object. The previous element from your split string need to be modified to add the current node as its child.

For example, if you split `"A/B/C"`, and iterate over it.

For `A`, First element - so its the root, check if `Instance` object is created for `A`, if not then create `A`. Store `A` in a `temp` variable to modify `A` later.

For `B`, `temp` holds the reference of `A`, check if `Instance` object is created for `B`, if not then create `B`. Modify `temp`'s `children` to add `B` to the list, let `temp` hold reference of `B`

For `C`, `temp` holds the reference of `B`, check if `Instance` object is created for `C`, if not then create `C`. Modify `temp`'s `children` to add `C` to the list, let `temp` hold reference of `C`.